# error: unknown type name ‘GtkObject’

Tags: c, gtk

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h>

static gboolean delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent  *event, gpointer data) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Set up window */
  GtkWidget *window;
  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(delete_event), NULL);

  /* Draw widgets */
  gtk_widget_show (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

That's my code, and I'm compiling like this:

```
gcc -o file `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gtksourceview-2.0` file.c
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
In file included from /usr/include/gtksourceview-2.0/gtksourceview/gtksourceview.h:30:0,
                 from lidedit.c:2:
/usr/include/gtksourceview-2.0/gtksourceview/gtksourcecompletion.h:60:2: error: unknown type name ‘GtkObject’
```

Comment: You are probably going to get a linker error later when you fix this problem. The libraries needs to come _after_ the files using the libraries on the build command line. So you need two `pkg-config` calls when building, one for the C flags and one for the libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gtksourceview 2 requires GTK+-2.  For use with GTK+-3 you should be using gtksourceview 3.